# Windows: Unable to create SSH keys

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

After domain migration, I am unable to load my public keys at all. I tried deleting them, recreating them but always getting same error as below

```
PS D:\Personal\OpenSSH-Win32> .\ssh-keygen.exe
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\raja/.ssh/id_rsa):
C:\Users\raja/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\raja/.ssh/id_rsa.
fopen C:\\Users\\raja/.ssh/id_rsa.pub failed: Permission denied
PS D:\Personal\OpenSSH-Win32>
```

I have tried fixing permissions

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.*
chmod: cannot access '/c/Users/raja/.ssh/id_rsa.*': No such file or directory
```

But seems failed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in windows, try to specify a valid path to store the file (it is, using backslash instead of slash):

Change from

C:\Users\raja/.ssh/id_rsa

to

C:\Users\raja\.ssh\id_rsa